# Observing from a true stationary point in space is there a "True time" we can observe?

Tags: time, relativity

Aren't all points on planets, in solar systems, in galaxies moving through space subject to different amounts of time dilation due to gravity and velocity when observed from a stationary point in space? Do we generally have a mathematical transformation to "true universal time" versus our dilated time with regards to how we view the universe? Does it in effect "lense" our view of the universe?

Comment: Search up "proper time"...I think that would be the best definition of the "true time". However, there really isn't any "true time" for **all** observers...that's the beauty, and the wackiness, of relativity. Also note, there is no "stationary point" in space, as there can't be a single reference point that's better than the rest.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a stationary point in space, so there is no universal time.

Answer (score 0):

As *trula's* answer reveals there is no place in the universe and never has been that allows a static observer. Think of it like we're all under water floating around and nobody is excluded.

We can't have an objective "point" from which to measure all others. All measurements are **relative**.

20 meters floating in strong current is different from 20 meters in placid water.

When we get in a strong current we might not notice it unless we have something to compare it to. Normally we could see the riverbank passing by more quickly but if there is no riverbank we have to judge by the bodies in the water. It's hard to know what currents are moving them though unless we get in their position.

If you pass another human by under water they may seem to be going fast but maybe it's you that is moving quickly and they think they are slow.

If we go to their position to find out what's going on we give up our own position and can't compare anymore.

Each person measures things from their own perspective and there is no fixed time.